# libtool failing to load a library

Tags: autoconf, automake, libtool

Can anyone provide any insight or way to debug why ltdl is failing to load my library?
As you can see from the partial strace output it succeeds in opening the library, then reports `file not found`, and then moves on to successfully load another library built the same way.  How can I debug this?  I have been googling for ages and found no useful ways of debugging it.

```
open("server/modules/smtp.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("server/modules/smtp.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
getcwd("/home/david/Documents/workspace/dvnmon", 128) = 39
1327209900.751672 3602 Failed to open server/modules/smtp: file not found
open("server/modules/snmp.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("server/modules/snmp.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
getcwd("/home/david/Documents/workspace/dvnmon", 128) = 39
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so.15", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
1327209900.800507 3602 Plugin CSNMPMonitor interface version 0.1 loaded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lt_dlopen()` reports `FILE_NOT_FOUND` whenever it fails to load a dynamic library.  This can happen even if the file exists.

I would first compare the output of `ldd server/modules/smtp.so` and that of `ldd server/modules/snmp.so`.  Maybe one of the two has a missing dependency?

You may also want to try `export LD_DEBUG=all` (see `man ld.so` for details).

Also it's not clear from your question if the files in `server/modules/` are actually Libtool modules.  If they are, why aren't the `*.la` files present?  These files may specify dependent libraries that need to be loaded first.

Comment: Cool thanks thats exactly what I needed.
     18996: server/modules/smtp.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZTI11CSMTPServer (fatal)
The .la files are not found because Im symlinking all the models into the same directory and for some reason the symlinks to the .la files don't work but it still fails to load the smtp one if I point it at the real files or copy them into that directory. The missing symbol is one of mine that has to do with using utility .a files to break apart the program and its obviously leaving that symbol out at the time the parent program is compiled